# Can I send data from my old Windows 7 to Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7

I recently downloaded Ubuntu to run side by side by my Windows but Ubuntu only has 10gb of space and Windows has 130gb. Is it possible to send data from my Windows to Ubuntu? because I find Linux better for gaming and I need a lot more space than 10gb to run all those games.

Comment: In Ubuntu, can able to access the partitions of windows by mounting but transferring can do only with external or USB drives which will be efficient way to transfer the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can access any partition you can access via Windows via Ubuntu (but not the other way around). This includes your system partition.

If you have an external storage device (usb stick, external hard drive), you can copy your data from the Windows partition to that device. Then remove it from the Windows partition (clean trash). After you did so, boot the PC with a live usb stick, launch GParted, decrease the size of the Windows partition, and increase the one of the Ubuntu partition. Then boot Ubuntu and copy the files back from the usb stick / external hard drive.

But remember that things can go wrong when changing partitions. Make a backup in advance, in case for example the power goes down and you're on a computer without backup power supply. Also, depending on your version of Windows, it may fail to boot after you played with the partitions. But this can be solved pretty easily by inserting the Windows DVD.